# Add Condition on generated numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have piece of code :

```
V = numpy.floor(3*np.random.rand(5,5))
print V
```

It create random result of array in 5x5 table, how to add condition "1" only generate x times, "2" only generate y times, else are "0".
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

def newArray( x, y, n):
    if x + y > n ** 2:
        print "Values error!"
        return
    res = [[0 for col in range(n)] for row in range(n)]
    # Create roulette
    roulette = range(0, n ** 2)

    printkxtimes(res, roulette, 1, x, n)
    printkxtimes(res, roulette, 2, y, n)
    print res

# This function draws random element from roulette, 
# gets the position in array and sets value of this position to k. 
# Then removes this element from roulette to prevent drawing it again
def printkxtimes(array, roulette, k, x, n):
    for i in xrange(0, x):
        r = int(np.floor(roulette.__len__()*np.random.rand(1))[0])
        array[roulette[r] / n][roulette[r] % n] = k
        roulette.pop(r)

newArray(10,2,5)
```

**A little explanation of `roulette` :**

Every element of table `res` can be represented equivalently  with a number from `range(0, n^2)` :

```
z = row*n + column <=> row = int(z/n) , column= z%n
```

We can then represent the list of positions in table `res` as the table `[0,1,...,n^2-1]`

Comment: Work like a charm... thanks... by the way can you explain each part of it if you dont mind.

Comment: @RikudoPain I've added some comments and an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
import numpy as np
shape = (5, 5)
area = shape[0] * shape[1]
np.random.permutation([1]*x + [2]*y + [0]*(area-x-y)).reshape(shape)
```

Seems pretty simple. You take a random permutation of `[1, ... 1, 2, ... 2, 0, ... 0]` and then you just turn it into a square. I'm not too sure but it also seems less computationally expensive and is also extensible to `n` numbers or dimensions quite easily.